# Hex byte calculation from Java to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, arrays

Getting a mismatch when trying to convert the Java code below to JavaScript, the output is every so slightly different.

**Java**

```
byte ex[] = new byte[26];
bits = 304;
for (int loop=0; loop<8; ++loop) {
    ex[ex.length-1-loop] = (byte)(0xFF&(bits>>(loop*8)));
    System.out.println("Ex value: " + ex[ex.length-1-loop]);
}
```

Console output:

```
Ex value: 48
Ex value: 1
Ex value: 0
Ex value: 0
Ex value: 0
Ex value: 0
Ex value: 0
Ex value: 0
```

**JavaScript**

```
var ex = new Int8Array(26);
var bits = 304;
for (var loop = 0; loop < 8; ++loop) { 
    ex[ex.length - 1 - loop] = (0xFF & (bits >> (loop * 8)));
    console.log("Ex value: " + ex[ex.length-1-loop]);
}
```

Console output:

```
> "Ex value: 48"
> "Ex value: 1"
> "Ex value: 0"
> "Ex value: 0"
> "Ex value: 48"
> "Ex value: 1"
> "Ex value: 0"
> "Ex value: 0"
```

You can see the errant 48 and 1 in the JavaScript. The Java is working as expected, I need the JS to match it.

For the errant calculations loop is 4 (for 48) and 5 (for 1). Both need to be zero.

That being said I tried the Java again without assigning the value to the array and got the SAME as JavaScript. I can't figure out why assigning it to the byte array makes a difference:

```
byte c = (byte)(0xFF&(304>>(4*8)));
int d = (byte)(0xFF&(304>>(5*8)));
System.out.println("c: " + c);
System.out.println("d: " + d);
```

Output:

```
c: 48
d: 1
```

### Edit

I dove down a bit more and found what appears to be occurring, see [Java hex calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53291811/java-hex-calculation). When a solution is found I'll delete one of these questions.