# Java hex calculation

Tags: javascript, java, hex, long-integer, calculation

I have the `long` value `bits` declared like so:

`long bits = len*8L;` (304)

`System.out.println(bits);` This outputs as 304

If I use the long name bits like so I get 0 & 0 respectively.

```
System.out.println(bits>>(4*8));
System.out.println(0xFF&(bits>>(4*8)));
```

If I use the actual number, like so, I get 304 and 48 respectively

```
System.out.println(304>>(4*8));
System.out.println(0xFF&(304>>(4*8)));
```

I'm trying to convert this Java to JavaScript but JavaScript gives me 304 and 48 in all scenarios. I need it to match the Java and give values of 0 & 0.

### Edit

Follow up, just to be clear, I need the JavaScript equivalent to equal 0, mimicking how the Java currently does it (the two examples above that equal 0 won't be changed in what we're developing).

So console.log(0xFF&(bits>>(4*8))) should equal 0, it currently equates to 48

Comment: In Java, `304` is an `int`, so there is an implicit `((4*8)%32)` for the number of bits to shift. `bits` is a `long`, so there is an implicit `((4*8)%64)`. JavaScript, I don't know...

Comment: And to followup on @KenY-N Javascript does all shifts as a 32bit number. So shifting by 32bits is ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JLS, Section 15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) covers shifting operators in Java.

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is `int`, then only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value `0x1f` (`0b11111`). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range `0` to `31`, inclusive.

For an `int` value such as `304`, the bit shift value of `4*8`, or 32, is really `0`, so no shifting takes place.  Then a bit-and with `0xFF` yields `48`.

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is `long`, then only the six lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value `0x3f` (`0b111111`). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range `0` to `63`, inclusive.

For a `long` value, the bit shift value of `4*8` really does shift to the right 32 bits, which yields `0`.

[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) covers JavaScript bit-shift operators.

> Bitwise operators treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits (zeroes and ones), rather than as decimal, hexadecimal, or octal numbers.

It appears that JavaScript converts the number to a 32-bit number, like a Java `int`.  It also appears that the same "only the least 5 bits" rule applies to the shift operand in JavaScript also.

```js
console.log(304>>32);        // Don't shift!
console.log(0xFF&(304>>32)); // Don't shift!
console.log(304>>33);        // Shift by 1, not 33
console.log(0xFF&(304>>33)); // Shift by 1, not 33
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check out the JavaScript bit-shift operators. I need the JavaScript to equal 0, like Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the same result with constants in Java as with variables, you need to pass 304 as a long constant with `304L`, like this:

```
System.out.println(304L>>(4*8));
System.out.println(0xFF&(304L>>(4*8)));
```

The reason is that you cannot shift an `int` with 4*8=32 bits; Java will shift 32 modulo 32 = zero buts, since an `int` is only 32 bits long.

Javascript, in constrast, doesn't support shifting 64-bit integers with the `>>` operator; it treats every number that you pass to `>>` as a 32-bit integer.

You could write your own function that does something similar:

```
function rshift(num, bits) {
    return Math.round(num / Math.pow(2,bits));
}

console.log(rshift(304, 4*8))
```

Comment: The rshift almost worked. One of the calculations is 0*8 for bits, which gives a value of 304. The Java equivalent gives 48

Comment: You're saying that the Java code `System.out.println(304L >> (0*8))` gives you 48? Or that `System.out.println(0xff & (304L >> (0*8)))`? Gives you 48? Because the equivalent of the latter is `console.log(0xff & rshift(304, 0*8))` and that outputs 48 in Javascript too.